# Activiti : Need to access timer trigger count

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I have a boundary timer event in user task connected to a mail task, for remainder, scheduled to trigger once every week, for three times. It is working but now I want to get the trigger count in the mail task so that I can send mail like "Remainder 1", "Remainder 2" etc. How to get the trigger count?

Answer (score 1):

You can store counter as process variable.

Comment: Why it is not an answer? He can store a process variable to count triggering of timer event and use this variable in mail template.